# Powershell7 dll loading into VSCode script

Tags: powershell

My Project: To build an automated task to weekly or monthly save gmail report attachments to Win10 folders for further analysis. This is currently done as a manual process.
The platform is a local Win10-PC and does not use Outlook365. Local Outlook.exe linked to Gmail.

Powershell 7x is the platform and various coding strategies have been attempted and failed.
Numerous suggestions from Stackoverflow have been studied with no success.
Latest attempt is by using the Codeplex distribution of ImapiX.zip but working with ImapiX I have never been able to use the dll sucessfully.

---

Using the code variants as follows.

```
$dllFile="C:\Users\Al Perkins\Desktop\OL_AutoSaveAttachments\imapiX-Source\sourceCode\ImapX\bin\Release\ImapX.dll"
$dll=[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dllFile) 

# Result
$dll

ImapX, Version=2.0.0.19, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5992873d65130d1f
```

So it appears to load as expected in VSCode.

```
$dllFile="C:\Users\Al Perkins\Desktop\OL_AutoSaveAttachments\imapiX-Source\sourceCode\ImapX\bin\Release\ImapX.dll"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dllFile)    

# difference is the Loadfile is not captured to var.
# The terminal window reports that the dll also loaded as expected.
 
GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v4.0.30319     C:\Users\Al Perkins\Desktop\OL_AutoSaveAttachments\imapiX-Source\sourceCode\ImapX\bin\Release\ImapX.dll
```

HOWEVER either way when I get to use the dll methods it seems they are not available?

```
$client = New-Object ImapiX.ImapClient

New-Object: C:\Users\Al Perkins\Desktop\OL_AutoSaveAttachments\DLAttachments.ps1:27:11
Line |
  27 |  $client = New-Object ImapiX.ImapClient
     |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot find type [ImapiX.ImapClient]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

And this similarly fails with any subsequent IMAPI method.

So I guess the dll is not built correctly but now this is way out of my scope.
My ask here is for any relevant suggestions as to how I might correct this issue.

Many Thanks
AL

Comment: When you have called `New-Object` is `ImapiX.ImapClient` a typo in your question or is it in the code too? The namespace is [`ImapX](https://github.com/azanov/imapx/blob/master/ImapX/ImapClient.cs).

Comment: After installing the NuGet package, both of these work for me, `[ImapX.ImapClient]::new()` and `New-Object -TypeName ImapX.ImapClient`. I imported the library with `Add-Type -Path "C:\path\to\package\ImapX.2.0.0.18\lib\net46\ImapX.dll"`. FYI, the [GitHub project](https://github.com/azanov/imapx) is no longer maintained and they recommend that people use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit).

Answer (score 0):

I am here to eat crow. Issue Solved & closed.
I searched my code and file/folder structure and as Ash suggested the typo was the problem.
The were several instances of ImapiX and in my septuagenarian brain I was not detecting this. I was 'conjugating' MAPI and imap. Duhh!

Additionally the failing dll employed was only 4K whereas a new build by myself is 103K. This worked. I also opted to use Powershell Add-Type which was less ambiguous for me.

Many Thanks to Ash from a fellow limey in Canada ,for your help. All we need sometimes is help to re-focus. :)
Al